# Find the rational points on $1 + 18 x + 81 x^2 + 44 x^3 = y^2$ with Sage

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, math-software, elliptic-curves, sagemath

I'm trying to use Sage on-line,but I meet some trouble with the code of it.
I want to find the rational points on an ellipse curve,such as $$1 + 18 x + 81 x^2 + 44 x^3 = y^2,\tag1$$
I know that $(x,y)=(0,1)(1,\pm12)(-\frac{1}{11},0)$ are on the curve,but I don't know how to find more,so I try to solve it with the math-software Sage.

What should I input?Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Multiply by $44^2$,we can difine the ellipse curve by this way,

E = EllipticCurve([0,81,0,44*18,44^2])

Then how to find the rational points on it?

Comment: Since this question has been linked to elliptic curves, should it be better to tag it as such? Regards.

Comment: You could always try asking [here](http://ask.sagemath.org/questions/).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203484/how-to-compute-rational-or-integer-points-on-elliptic-curves  has links to some examples .

Comment: BTW, `E.rational_points(bound=1000)` took several *days* to return the output `[(-4 : 0 : 1), (0 : -44 : 1), (0 : 1 : 0), (0 : 44 : 1), (44 : -528 : 1), (44 : 528 : 1)]` -- so knowing the mathematics in the answers below certainly helps. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the Mordell-Weil theorem, the group of rational points $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is finitely generated and therefore isomorphic to a group of the form $T\oplus \mathbb{Z}^R$, where $T$ is finite abelian formed by those points of finite order, and $R\geq 0$ is the rank of the elliptic curve, and it counts how many $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent points of infinite order there are.

With Sage, define your curve by

> E=EllipticCurve([0,81,0,44*18,44^2]);

Now you can ask Sage to calculate the rank $R$ with

> E.rank();

and the answer is $0$. So there are no points of infinite order, only finite order points. Let us calculate the torsion subgroup as follows

> T=E.torsion_subgroup();

if you type ``T;'' and evaluate, Sage will tell you that $T\cong \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$. Finally, if you type

> T.0;

Sage returns a generator of the torsion subgroup, namely $P=(44,528)$, which is a point of exact order $6$. Hence, $E(\mathbb{Q})=\langle P \rangle$ or
$$E(\mathbb{Q})=\langle P \rangle = \{ \mathcal{O}, (44,528),(0,44), (-4,0), (0,-44), (44,-528)\}.$$

Comment: Thanks!May I ask what should I do when E.rank()$\ge$1 ?For example,E = EllipticCurve([0,121,0,22*52,52^2]);then E.rank()=1,now how can I find the point which rank is infinte?

Comment: Just like Jesper Petersen explains in another answer.

Answer (score 5):

In case a curve has positive rank, you'd like to know its generators by E.gens().

In the case

```
E = EllipticCurve([0,121,0,22*52,52^2]);
```

the rank is 1

```
sage: E.rank()
1
```

and its generator is

```
sage: E.gens()
[(-104 : 260 : 1)]
```

In this case you can construct infinitely many points on E, by adding a torsion point and some multiple of the generator, for instance

```
sage: T = E(0,52)
sage: P = E(-104,260) 
sage: T + 2*P
(480/49 : 55796/343 : 1)
sage: T + 3*P
(-12662312/485809 : -65467251044/338608873 : 1)
sage: T - 5*P
(-70265016926482573/11385999920450401 : 5045808098009295785013222/1214945410097644049235601 : 1)
```

and so on.