# Solving the Diophantine equation $k^2(k+1)=m(3m-1)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, integers

I am working on solving the following Diophantine equation:

$$k^2(k+1)=m(3m-1)$$

And so far I solved, using [WolframAlpha](http://solve%20(k%5E2(k+1)=m*(3*m-1))%20over%20the%20integers), the following solutions:

$$(k,m)=(-1,0);(0,0);(1,1);(4,-5);(6,-9)$$

Is there a way to prove that those are the only ones?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: This is an elliptic curve given by $3y^2-y=x^3+x^2$. Its integer points can be computed, see for example the following post (we might transform to short Weierstrass form $y^2=x^3+ax+b$ if necessary).

[How to compute rational or integer points on elliptic curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203484/how-to-compute-rational-or-integer-points-on-elliptic-curves)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103436/discussion-on-answer-by-dietrich-burde-solving-the-diophantine-equation-k2k1).

Answer (score 0):

(k,m)=(-2/3),(-1/9) &
(k,m)=(-2/3),(4/9)

The above are also the solutions to the equation asked by "OP".

Comment: $k^2(k+1)=m(3m-1)$

⇒$3m^2-m-k^2(k+1)=0$

⇒ $m=\frac{1±\sqrt {\Delta}}{6}$

The discriminant $\Delta$ is:

$\Delta=1+12k^2(k+1)≥ 0$

Only $k=-1, 0, 1, 4, 6 $ give perfect square for $\Delta$ .