# Prove the solutions of Diophantine equation are limited

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

During solving another equation, I found equation $1+12k^2(k+1)=t^2$ has limited solution in $\mathbb Z$:

$(k, t)=(0,±1), (1, ±5), (-1, ±1), (4,±31), (6,±55)$

I found this to be true by Python up to $k=10^6$. Prove or disprove this analytically.

Comment: Now we have a circle of posts regarding this question. It started with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3508812/solving-the-diophantine-equation-k2k1-m3m-1), then went [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509019/finding-integral-points-on-an-elliptic-y2-3y-x3x2-curve-using-the-lmfdb-da) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509271/finding-the-corresponding-subsitution-to-find-elliptic-curve-3b2-b-a3a2)...

Comment: ... coming back now at the present question to the first post asking again for $1+12k^2(k+1)=t^2$, see one answer at this original post. Now the answer by Robert closes the circle. Perhaps this could be joined somehow and superflous posts deleted or combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an elliptic curve.  According to a theorem of Siegel, it has only finitely many integer points.

EDIT: The Weierstrass form of this curve is $$x^3 + y^2 - 48 x - 272 = 0 $$
where $x = -12 k - 4$ and $y = 12 t$.  Note that integer $(k,t)$ imply integer $(x,y)$ but not vice versa.  Sage gives me the integer points  $(x,y)$:

```
x, y = var('x,y')
E = EllipticCurve(x^3 - 48*x + 272 == y^2)
E.integral_points(both_signs=True)

[(-8 : -12 : 1),
 (-8 : 12 : 1),
 (-4 : -20 : 1),
 (-4 : 20 : 1),
 (1 : -15 : 1), 
 (1 : 15 : 1),
 (4 : -12 : 1),
 (4 : 12 : 1),
 (8 : -20 : 1), 
 (8 : 20 : 1), 
 (16 : -60 : 1), 
 (16 : 60 : 1), 
 (52 : -372 : 1), 
 (52 : 372 : 1), 
 (76 : -660 : 1), 
 (76 : 660 : 1), 
 (1721 : -71395 : 1), 
 (1721 : 71395 : 1)]
```

Looking at the corresponding $(k,t)$ pairs, the only ones in integers are those you found.

Comment: Thank you Robert.